# Capture data from jQuery Mobile GUI / form elements like sliders, or the flip switch/toggle, and store in a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, mobile

I have this code, which executes without error, it shows "** slider change **" in the debug console every time the slider changes. But I cannot figure out how to capture the value of the slider so I can store it in a var. Can you help, I'm hoping it's a simple thing.

```
$('#page4_Options').live('pageinit', function(event) {

    var slideTime = userOptions.getSlideTime() / 1000; // userOptions is my Object to get/set params from localStorage.

    $("input[id='slider']").val(slideTime).slider("refresh"); // set default slide time when page init's.

    console.log("userOptions.getSlideTime()", userOptions.getSlideTime()); 

    $("#slider").bind("slidestop", function(event, ui) { 
        console.log("** slider change **");
        // How do I capture the new slider value into a var?
     });
});
```

Here's the HTML with the slider, it's in a  tag:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="slider">Slide Duration (seconds):</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="2" min="0" max="60" />
</div>
```